# Identification of two terminal component with top marking ON B48 MPC

Tags: power-supply, identification, components

[image: photo of component on PCB]

What kind of component is this? The PCB silkscreen says V1.

Comment: Welcome! Please crop your image. Most probably a diode, but if you take the photo from above and zoom out a bit, it’s easier to tell what it does in the circuit.

Comment: V might be Varistor. Do On Semi (formerly Motorola) make varistors? If so, they probably catalog their device markings.

Comment: V is prefix in several e-CAD programs for diodes as default. Most probably a diode, second if not a diode, it’s a varistor.

Comment: This board is power supply for allen bradley micrologic 1200